# UK visa application - questions about Schengen entry

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

There is a question regarding travel history to Schengen Area in UK Visa application form.

How many times have you visited the following places in the past 10 years?

Australia
Canada
New Zealand
USA
Schengen area

I have been to Schengen Area once 5 years ago, my visa was issued from Greece consulate so my entry point was Greece, though for 1 day only. My Itinerary was as below:

1. Greece (1 day)
2. Italy (3 days)
3. Switzerland (7 days)
4. France (4 days)

Total trip for 15 days to Schengen area.

I have one entry stamp from Greece and one exit stamp from France, since Paris was my last stop.

So, which country shall I mention in UK visa application form as system allows you to enter the trip detail one time only if we choose the option (Once) under 'Travel History' for Schengen Area? And suppose if I choose Greece (as it was my entry point/also visa issued from Greece) for the question 'Which country in the Schengen area? then how many days should I enter under 'Number of days, weeks or months' field?

Please advise.

Comment: For next time, note that having a Schengen visa issued by Greece doesn't mean you have to enter Schengen there. And you should have had your visa issued by the country that was the main focus of your visit, which looks like it was Switzerland.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are asking for 'Schengen Area' use that, with 15 as the amount of days.

Since the entry/exit stamps confirm that, there should be no problem.

Had they asked for 'Schengen Countries' then the list of countries would what they want, this is, however, not the case.

---

The Online form (which the user is using) is different than the vaf1a pdf form, which does not contain the same question.

There is no Guidance pdf that offers more help.

So this should be **properly** clarified.

Advice given is **Country of entry (Greece)** and 15 days,
since it can be varified during any interview or immigration control.

Comment: I still did not get my answer. They are asking 'Which Country in Schengen Area' and that was main question as which specific country I need to mention since I can list only one country as system does not allow me to enter no. of countries for Schengen Area.  My entry and exit stamps are from two different countries, hence there is a confusion as which country I need to mention.

Comment: The question is 'Which Country in Schengen Area' and for that I need to mention the one specific Schengen country.

Comment: I don't see this question on the form. Have also looked at the Guidance notes?

Comment: Can you supply the question number.? And the form is for vist or short term stay?

Comment: Oh, this an online form?

Comment: I don't know which form you are referring to, I am using new application form (GIV.UK) for UK Standard Visa form.

Comment: Yes, new online form (GOV.UK)

Comment: I cannot access that since an acount is needed. The introduction information states travel history with destination.

Comment: Without further information from the site what it means, I would chose country of entry (Greece ).

Comment: Ok and how many days of visit shall I enter? My total stay in schengen area was 15 days but I stayed one night only in Greece and my last exit stamp was from France.

Comment: This is something that must be guessed i'm afraid. I would suggest 15 since this can be varified, wheras 1 cannot.